# Remove specific characters

Tags: bash, shell, awk

How can I remove '-' and the characters before '-' using awk or any command?

```
XR-234|YYY|YYY|IR-567
YYYY|GT-890|YYYY|YYYY
```

OUTPUT:

```
234|YYY|YYY|567
YYYY|890|YYYY|YYYY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/^[^-]+-/,"",$i)}1' inputfile
```

`FS` and `OFS` are set to "|" inside BEGIN block. Then for each field, to the replacement and print using `gsub` function.

Answer (score 0):

More simple when use `sed`

```
sed 's/[^|]\+-//g' inputfile
```

Comment: Note that `\+` relies on GNU sed - you can use `\{1,\}` instead or add the `-E` switch and use `+`.

Answer (score 0):

try in awk too:

```
awk '{gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+-/,"")} 1'   Input_file
```

Global substituting alphabets till dash(-) to NULL and then mentioning the Input_file here.

Answer (score 0):

Using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
sed 's/[^|]*-//g' fil
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Removes two characters  and dash.

```
awk '{gsub(/..-/,"")}1' file

234|YYY|YYY|567
YYYY|890|YYYY|YYYY
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[^|-]+-/,"")}1' file
234|YYY|YYY|567
YYYY|890|YYYY|YYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl script language,

```
#!/use/bin/Perl
use warnings;
use strict;
while(<>){
     s/(\w)*-//;
     print;
}
```

Execute this script as below,
    perl script.pl your_test_file

This gives your desired output,

```
234|YYY|YYY|567
YYYY|890|YYYY|YYYY
```